# jquery and post method security with an https url

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, post, ssl

suppose I do

```
$.post('https://somesite.com', {username : "somename", password : "somepassword"}, function(){
   //do something
});
```

notice that the site's url is prefixed with https...

Does this imply that jquery will use HTTPS connection to relay that username and password info?

IE. will this prevent some hacker from intercepting that message and obtain the username and password data? IE. is this just as secure as logging in manually with a form in a https enabled site?

If not, what should I do to make this post transmission just as secure as someone manually logging into a site using a login form...(Ie. make it unable to be intercepted by some hacker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the login is fine,  but this doesn't guarantee the session is secure.   You probably haven't read [OWASP a9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection), and your application is probably vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

First, jQuery doesn't do anything. It's plain javascript, and jQuery simply build over it.

Secondly, that will plainly not work, because of cross-domain policy.

Thirdly, there's the issue mentioned by @Rook which is very important IMHO.